How can I obtain or create encryption scopes for an Azure storage account by using dotnet?
This document details the operations on encryption scopes.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/aiservices/accountmanagement/encryption-scopes/get?view=rest-aiservices-accountmanagement-2024-10-01&tabs=dotnet#examples
However, I'm not familiar with this.
TokenCredential cred = new DefaultAzureCredential(); // authenticate your client ArmClient client = new ArmClient(cred);
I usually use the storage account access key to interact with my containers and perform blob file uploads and downloads. Is it possible to obtain/create encryption scopes in a similar manner (by using the storage account access key)?
Edit:
Thank you very much for your reply. What I need to do is to create a container with an encryption scope through this code. Since the encryption scope is not created in advance, it needs to be created by code when creating the container. Since operating the encryption scope requires AAD authentication, is there a way to access it through something like a token?

var blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString); var
containerClient =
blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(blobContainerName); await
containerClient.CreateIfNotExistsAsync(PublicAccessType.None, null,
new BlobContainerEncryptionScopeOptions {
PreventEncryptionScopeOverride = true, DefaultEncryptionScope =
blobContainerName });

Is this method of creating a container with an encryption scope and creating the encryption scope at the same time a good practice? Are there any better practices?

Encryption scopes in Azure are account-level constructs that are part of Azure's advanced data protection features. These are used to define how data is encrypted within Azure Storage accounts. The operations on encryption scopes, such as creating, updating, or retrieving encryption scopes, are typically managed through the Azure Resource Manager (ARM) API or SDKs, which rely on Azure Active Directory (AAD) authentication instead of storage account access keys.

Thank you very much for your reply. I've edited my question and added some new ones. Could you please take a look again and see if you can help?


How can I obtain or create encryption scopes for an Azure storage account by using dotnet?

Encryption scope management is an administrative operation performed via the Azure Resource Manager (ARM) API, which requires Azure AD-based authentication (like using DefaultAzureCredential or ClientSecretCredential).
Storage account keys are designed for data plane operations and cannot be used for ARM operations.
Assign Contributor role to the user to access the encryption scopes for an Azure storage account.
Here the sample code that will get the details of Azure Storage encryption scope using .NET.
Code:
using Azure.Core;
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.ResourceManager;
using Azure.ResourceManager.Storage;


class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        TokenCredential cred = new DefaultAzureCredential();
        ArmClient client = new ArmClient(cred);

        string subscriptionId = "xxxx";
        string resourceGroupName = "xx";
        string accountName = "xxx";
        string encryptionScopeName = "xx";

        ResourceIdentifier encryptionScopeResourceId = EncryptionScopeResource.CreateResourceIdentifier(
            subscriptionId, resourceGroupName, accountName, encryptionScopeName);

        EncryptionScopeResource encryptionScope = client.GetEncryptionScopeResource(encryptionScopeResourceId);

        EncryptionScopeResource result = await encryptionScope.GetAsync();
        EncryptionScopeData resourceData = result.Data;

        // Display full details of the EncryptionScopeData
        Console.WriteLine("Encryption Scope Details:");
        Console.WriteLine($"- Name: {resourceData.Name}");
        Console.WriteLine($"- Type: {resourceData.ResourceType}");
        Console.WriteLine($"- Id: {resourceData.Id}");
        Console.WriteLine($"- State: {resourceData.State}");
        Console.WriteLine($"- Source: {resourceData.Source}");
        Console.WriteLine($"- Key Vault Key Uri: {resourceData.KeyVaultProperties.KeyUri}");
        Console.WriteLine($"- Creation Time: {resourceData.CreatedOn}");
        Console.WriteLine($"- Last Modified Time: {resourceData.LastModifiedOn}");
    }
}

Output:
Encryption Scope Details:
- Name: testvenkat
- Type: Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/encryptionScopes
- Id: /subscriptions/xxxx/resourceGroups/venkatesan-rg/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/venkat326123/encryptionScopes/testvenkat
- State: Enabled
- Source: Microsoft.Keyvault
- Key Vault Key Uri: https://venkat678.vault.azure.net/keys/xxxx
- Creation Time: 20-12-2024 08:47:51 +00:00
- Last Modified Time: 20-12-2024 08:47:51 +00:00


Reference:
Encryption Scopes - Get - REST API (Azure Storage Resource Provider) | Microsoft Learn

Thank you very much for your reply. I've edited my question and added some new ones. Could you please take a look again and see if you can help?
